# Error accessing the Cache in the Application_Start method of Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, global-asax

I am trying to access the Cache in the Application_Start method of Global.asax. I am trying to accdess Context.Cache. When I run the code from visual studio it works just fine but when I run it on the server from IIS I get: Session state is not available in this context. I want to seed some values in the cache when the application starts. How can I get at the cache from Application_Start?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow. I found the answer to this. Use the variable HttpRuntime.Cache instead of Context.Cache.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this changed in IIS7 with the switch to integrated mode. Application_Start executes earlier so the HttpContext is not available.

Visual Studio uses Cassini which differs from full IIS in several ways. Check out the newly released [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) which can also be used with Visual Studio. It's a self-contained version of IIS 7.5 so you won't hit problems in production that didn't exist when testing using Cassini.